# Программное изменение типа аутентификации

Tags: asp.net, c#

Хотелось бы узнать, можно ли программным способом изменять файл web.config, конкретно, изменить `authentication mode=""`? Чтобы юзер мог выбрать, через БД ему авторизоваться либо через `active directory`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Столько я ещё не гуглил никогда =). Но зато добившись результата и получив моральное удовлетворение, вдохновился на дальнейшую работу. Код для последователей:

```
 
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Configuration;
System.Configuration.Configuration configuration =     WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
AuthenticationSection authenticationSection =    (AuthenticationSection)configuration.GetSection("system.web/authentication");
authenticationSection.Mode = AuthenticationMode.Windows; //чтобы вернуть назад соответственно ставим .Forms
configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
```

Comment: И что работает? Неужели можно без перезапуска приложения?

Comment: Да, работает, изобретал долго, единственное что после выполнения этого кода необходимо постбек сделать, поэтому я решил сделать радиобутон с выбором вида авторизации с постбеком, а снизу ещё кнопку с перенаправлением на другую страницу, и вот после нажатия на кнопку аутентификация изменяется и пользователь получает необходимый результат.

Answer (score 3):

Web.config - это обычный xml файл, и работать с ним можно как с обычным xml файлом. Но! При изменении его потребуется перезапуск приложения, поэтому что-то менять в нем программно не желательно.
Для решения вашей задачи, я бы попробовал сделать так: как известно файлы web.config можно создавать в каждой папке приложения. Значит требуется создать две папки в них создать свои web.config-и и прописать в них в разные режимы аутентификации. Также в папках создайте по странице aspx, в которых собственно и будет происходить аутентификация. Я так никогда не делал, и не знаю будет работать или нет. Если будете пробовать так делать, то потом отпишите, пожалуйста, работает или нет.